# Permalinks on Wordpress EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, permalinks

I have just transferred my blog from my local webserver to Amazon EC2 Free Linux server, Everything seems to be working now except for permalinks, I disabled and re-enabled them and it still breaks.

I've tried running the script

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

But it says a2enmod: command not found while logged into my server as ec2-user

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I just had this same issue and, assuming you are using httpd, you will need to go to `/etc/httpd/conf` then open http.conf by running `sudo vi httpd.conf` and then change "AllowOverride" to:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

You may also need to change `AllowOverride All` here:

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride All
```

Then you need to restart httpd by running `apachectl -k restart`. Note, you may need to actually run `sudo apachectl -k restart`.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hey Carl, can't thank you more! especially the `sudo apachecl -k restart` part. Couldn't find that on other sources and was so frustrated... Thanks!

Comment: `apachectl -k restart` didn't work for me, but `sudo service httpd restart` did

Comment: Had a friend with a similar issue, and her configuration was slightly different. Her wordpress install was in `var/www/html/`, and there was an `AllowOverride None` directive in the directory block for that specific directory.

In that case, you'll need to set the `AllowOverride` directive to `All` in the directory block for that specific folder - And I'd recommend leaving it to `None` for the other directory blocks that aren't using wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu, change the "AllowOverride All" at the following location:

"The additional step I had to take was to edit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.

In that file you'll find an AllowOverride setting for /var/www, saying "None".

Change the setting to say: AllowOverride All
"

Credit to ljonas @ http://wordpress.org/support/topic/solved-permalinks-working-in-apache2-ubuntu-1010

Answer (score 2):

There are written and video instructions located here https://a1websitepro.com/enable-pretty-permalinks-amazon-web-hosting/

```
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

Comment: The linked instructions explains that .htaccess has to be edited. Other posts suggest that it's just apache2.conf

Answer (score 2):

Basic: [Connecting to Your Linux Instance from Windows Using PuTTY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html)

Step 1: Open [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to login in AWS EC2 console

Step 2: Enter Server Address

[image]

Step 3: Browse Auth Private Key in PuTTY

[image]

Step 4: Login to AWS through PuTTY (Enter “Login as name” i.e. your AWS ec2 instance name. for above example: ec2-user)

Step 5: Change directory to /etc/httpd/conf  (`$ cd /etc/httpd/conf`)

Step 6: execute `sudo vi httpd.conf` to update httpd.conf file. (Open httpd.conf file in VI editor)

Update Following

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

To

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

And

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride None
```

To

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#

    AllowOverride All
```

Step 7: Save and Exit from VI editor.

To save and exit from VI editor press [Esc] key and type `:wq`

Step 8: Restart Apache

Type `sudo apachectl -k restart`

Final Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On AWS my file was in a slightly different location:

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

After changing `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in both locaitons and restarting with `sudo service httpd restart` permalink redirects work great!

Answer (score 0):

Your server may not have the AllowOverride directive enabled. If the AllowOverride directive is set to None in your Apache httpd.config file, then .htaccess files are completely ignored.

In this case, the server will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem. When this directive is set to All, then any directive which has the .htaccess Context is allowed in .htaccess files. Example of enabled AllowOverride directive in httpd.config:

`Options FollowSymLinks`

`AllowOverride All`

**This link may also be helpful:** http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Answer (score 0):

AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
 It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit

```
AllowOverride All
```

when i set this on my server, then i got 503  internal server error, any advi please?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the AllowOverride All and Options +FollowSymLinks in more than one .conf file (and I also tried a2enmod rewrite while I was at it). But it was the last .conf file that was apparently controlling that directory (the .iso we used resulted in several with the same directory ... and the first one I changed had no effect). But once they ALL had both those settings the system began working.