# routing apache server to express.js server

Tags: node.js, apache, express, proxy, routes

I built an node express server. It runs without any trouble: http://uniformflow.com

```
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log('listening on ' + port));
```

Recently, I got an ssl certificate from letsencrypt. I ended up having a secure working apache server, which you can check at https://www.uniformflow.com

At this point, I assume my express server listens the http port. And when someone sends a request with https port, It goes to my apache server /var/www directory. How should I route this requests to my node server?

Answer (score 0):

in Apache there is no module support for node like php or perl. so you should use  Apache proxy module. you can enable it using `sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_http` and then change its configurations in `/etc/apche2/sites-availables`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@uniformflow.com
    ServerName uniformflow.com
    ServerAlias www.uniformflow.com 

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

then you should restart apache server.
in my opinion its better to use Nginx, its very easy and i also handle ssl connection for you.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I've seen a2enmod in several guides. I'm using Amazon Linux 2 AMI, and it gives me the error: sudo: a2enmod: command not found.

Comment: @Meriç checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292992/permalinks-on-wordpress-ec2